# Can't remove background color from md button

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

On a hover state I'm trying to remove the background color of an md-button when I hover, but I'm not able to affect it.

I'm using Material 2

In my html I have the following:

```
<div class="case-nav-container">
  <div *ngFor="let item of nav">
    <a md-button           
       routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
       class = "case-button"
       [class.active]="rla.isActive">{{item.display}}</a> <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my SCSS I have:

```
a.case-button{

  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: left;

  &:hover{
    border-left: solid blue 6px;
    background-color: none;
  }

}
```

My question is how do I remove the bg-color of the button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change Angular Material button background color on hover state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342158/how-can-i-change-angular-material-button-background-color-on-hover-state)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The background color comes in the form of a focus overlay div. This will remove it,

**template:**

```
<a mat-button class="no-hover">Basic Button</a>
```

**css:**

```
.mat-button.no-hover ::ng-deep .mat-button-focus-overlay {
  background: none;
}
```

**demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-dyck3s

Comment: `/deep/` instead of `::ng-deep` if using sass

Comment: `::ng-deep` is recommended over `/deep/` by the Angular docs. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Yep! I've updated the example to using a sass component stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to increase the specificity of your SCSS.  Try `.case-nav-container a  .case-button`.  Your SCSS will need to address the element you are modifying more specifically than the Angular Material code is.  In some instances where increasing specificity isn't practical for an element a !important SCSS attribute will work as well to override the Angular Material default background color.