# How can I change Angular Material button background color on hover state?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an Angular button:

```
<button md-button class="link-btn" >Cancel</button>

.link-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0px;
}

.link-btn:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Normally it is setting transparent background, but in `hover` state, gray background is shown? How to remove that?

Comment: You can check my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401579/3339907

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of Angular 6, the use of /deep/ or ng-deep in the chosen solution is [marked for deprecation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). The recommended way is to use global styles as stated in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#styling-concepts).

> Some Angular Material components, specifically overlay-based ones like
>   MatDialog, MatSnackbar, etc., do not exist as children of your
>   component. Often they are injected elsewhere in the DOM. This is
>   important to keep in mind, since even using high specificity and
>   shadow-piercing selectors will not target elements that are not direct
>   children of your component. Global styles are recommended for
>   targeting such components.

In the specific case of button hover background, I had to use the following code in my styles.css (global stylesheet included via angular-cli or directly linked in index.html). Note that you might have to replace primary with accent or warn depending on the palette type (color="primary" or color="accent" or color="warn") used in the button.

```
.mat-button.mat-primary .mat-button-focus-overlay {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

If you don't want every button to be affected, it's better to have a specific class like no-hover-effect as shown below.

```
.no-hover-effect.mat-button.mat-primary .mat-button-focus-overlay,
.no-hover-effect.mat-button.mat-accent .mat-button-focus-overlay,
.no-hover-effect.mat-button.mat-warn .mat-button-focus-overlay
{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

For every material button that doesn't need hover-effect, you'd do

```
  <button mat-button color="primary" class="no-hover-effect">
    No Hover Button
  </button>
```

Comment: I found that the trick for the template I was using was to follow the :hover style background-color with !important.   The background color change would not reflect on hover unless I used !important.

Comment: Just a small note, but if anyone uses mat-button but not the color property (e.g. primary, accent, warn), then you can achieve the same outcome with this in styles.scss:

`.no-hover-effect.mat-button .mat-button-focus-overlay { background-color: transparent; }`

Answer (score 19):

The button styles are encapsulated, so you have to use /deep/ selector to change internal styles.

Try this:

```
.link-btn /deep/ .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9uaZXth2ZvcIfIxonnvw?p=preview)

## Update:

As of Angular v4.3.0 the `/deep/` selector is deprecated and will be replaced by the `::ng-deep` selector. You can find more info in the documentation: [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: how would you do this when /deep/ is removed?

Comment: As written in my answer, with `::ng-deep`

Comment: deep AND ::ng-deep will be depricated and removed:

The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

Source: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `mat-flat-button` instead of `mat-button` as the former doesn't have an overlay mechanic. You just need to override the background color in your component which is imho is a much cleaner mechanic than globally overriding dynamically created overlay components angular material creates.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following to your css...

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Or

```
.mat-menu-item:hover {
     background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a global style to your application to all the buttons.
I did it using Angular theming for the mat-icon-buttons.

```
$background: map-get($my-theme, background);

// add hover for mat-icon butttons
.mat-icon-button:hover {
   background-color: mat-color($background, hover);
 }
```